# Better way of showing images from a model in razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

EDIT: it was the @ViewBag.Persona(item.IDPersona) part the problem.

In a view I iterate over a collection of models, each model has an url that corresponds to an image in the server. I want to display in a table every model with its image. So I did something like this:

```
<table class="tbody">
    <tr class="th">
        <th>ID
        </th>
        <th>Person
        </th>
        <th>Image
        </th>


    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Entity)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.IDPersona.ToString(), "Edit", "Persona", new{Id = item.IDPersona}, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @ViewBag.Persona(item.IDPersona)
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="/img/@item.ImageName" height="100" width="100" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

But the page can take up to 13 seconds to load. I imagine that the reason is because I am loading one image at a time instead of loading multiple images simultaneously.

Is there a way to improve the loading time? Maybe "delaying" the load of the image until the model have been iterated entirely, is this possible?

Comment: you can use small version of images means thumbnail

Comment: Most images are ~20 kb anyway, and it's just 15 images in total, 13 seconds it's too much.

Comment: What's going on in your controller? Is it just grabbing an image off of the file system or reaching out to a network share? Is it resizing and cropping a larger image dynamically?

Comment: The controller get the collection of models (only 15) and just pass it to the view. The images and the razor file are on the same machine (it's local). But the whole controller executes really fast. The slow part is in the view (I know this because I used Stopwatch and just befaure returning the view it marked 0.6 seconds)

Comment: I'm thinking it might be something other than images causing the problem but I can't be sure without seeing what your `Model` looks like. And what's up with the `@ViewBag.Persona(item.IDPersona)` part?

Comment: I was just checking that right now. It's code that some coworker did. It was actually a complex query that was quite slow. Taking it out of the way solved the problem. Thanks (make some kind of answer to mark your answer)

Comment: Please take a minute to properly debug the issue.  One way to debug this problem is to do some [Performance Profiling in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, and going off of the details in your comments, I don't think it's the images causing the issue. If it's simply pulling the images off of the local file system it's not likely that they'd be the cause of the slowness.